# How do I store session and access it anywhere in my application in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, session

Code is given below. I have a  loginAction method and I want to access username through the session in my twig file.

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $session= $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    if($request->getMethod()=='POST')
    {

        $username=$request->get('username');
        $password=$request->get('password');

        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('MWANRegisterBundle:User');

        $user= $repository->findOneBy(array('userName'=>$username,    'userPassword'=> $password ));
        if($user)
        {
        $login= new Session(); 

     // Session is in the same class as getter setter functions
     // for username and password

        $login->setUsername($username);
        $session->set('login', $login);
          if($session->has('login'))
            {
            $login = $session->get('login');
            $username = $login->getUsername();
            //  var_dump($username); exit();

       // in show_home I redirect to twig file list.html.twig

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_home'));
            }

        }
        else
        {
        echo("wrong username   OR  password");
        exit();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MWANRegisterBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
 }
```

--------------------- Here is the logout method --------------------------

```
public function logoutAction(Request $request)
{
    $session= $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->clear();
    return $this->render('MWANRegisterBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
}

  // listAction is action to render list.html.twig i want username of     session here 

 public function listAction (Request $request)
 {
    $session= $this->getRequest()->getSession();

        return $this->render('MWANRegisterBundle:Default:list.html.twig' );

}
```

Kindly guide me step by step ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this "hack" to retrieve logged username, even in twig.

Simply use this snippet of code

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

If you want to be sure that user is currently logged in, you could add some explicit control

```
{% if app.user %}
  {{ app.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

For a complete answer, I add also session retrieval from twig

```
{{ app.session.get('parameterName') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access your sessions in twig by using `{{app.session.get("nameOfSession")}}` and setting session `{{app.session.set("name","value")}}`

for your user managment I suggest you to use [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) to have a best and  secur application

Comment: ===============  One More Question ===================

       $plainPassword = $this->get('request')->request->get('password');
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($entity, $plainPassword);
        $entity->setPassword($encoded);

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Gholami 

when i use bcrypt in Security.yml. it doesnot match with  password stored in DB after dynamically encoding it.

Comment: when you change encoding method you must empty user table and register your user again

Comment: MWAN\RegisterBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt  <---- i'm using this in scurity.yml class 
i follow your suggestion , deleted entries (record) from DB and register the user again ... after this  i attempt login which still gives Bad credentials.

Comment: check bcrypt installed

Comment: why you don`t use fosuserbundle?

Comment: get php info to see bcrypt installation